# HTTP Request in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, httprequest

I wrote the following code in Xamarin to connect the Web Server:

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create( "http://srv21.n-software.de/authentication.json") as HttpWebRequest;
        // request.Method = "GET";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("name", "demo");
        request.Headers.Add("password", "demo");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HttpWebResponse Httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

It connects to the web server and the web server gets the request for "authentication.json", but doesn't get the parameters of the header ("name" and "password"). 
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: How are you trying to read those headers on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your parameters need to be in the body of the `POST` request instead of in the headers. Alternatively you might try to use a `GET` request instead and provide the parameters through the URL, if your server supports it (i.e. `http://srv21.n-software.de/authentication.json?name=demo&password=demo`).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
using System.Net.Http;

string URL = "http://www.here.com/api/postForm.php";
string DIRECT_POST_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string postData = "username=usernameValueHere&password=passwordValueHere");

StringContent content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, DIRECT_POST_CONTENT_TYPE);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(DIRECT_GATEWAY_URL, content);

string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: You should always try to explain your answer and show _why_ it works.

Comment: I'm still learning myself. So I can't explain it. Just seems that the web server isn't looking in the header for the values. Also forgive the lack of using. That HttpClient is begging for one.